# Highcharts border

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

Is there a way to add a border to the plot area like the black border in the picture?

[image]

-- UPDATED --
I'm getting some white space between plot area and border. Is there a way to remove the white space?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update** Use plotBorder width for internal border. see the [updated fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/5d0rw06u/3/)

use this  :

```
 chart: {
        borderColor: '#EBBA95',// whatever you want
        borderWidth: 3 

    }
```

for black border use

```
borderColor:'#000000'
```

fiddle with border [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/5d0rw06u/1/)

Comment: Unfortunately the border added with borderColor covers the area the include also the legends and it's not good for me.

Comment: for that , use   plotBorderColor,  plotBorderWidth. I am updating the fiddle. See this http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/5d0rw06u/3/

Comment: @AndreaGirardi is fiddle is your expected result http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/5d0rw06u/3/